# Where to place 'transaction' criteria in a Splunk query

Tags: splunk

The intent here is to use the `Splunk`

```
 transaction startswith
```

in conjunction with a query that specifies a pair of fields and a free form search string.  What is the correct structuring/ordering of the query?

To start with: the following query returns a few records:

```
 index=dev sourcetype="alstest-tuning--1-0-50--*" Error
```

Now we want to view some records following each of the results.  Here are a couple of attempts:

```
 transaction startswith("index=dev sourcetype=\"alstest-tuning--1-0-50--*\" Error") maxevents=20
```

and

```
 index=dev sourcetype="alstest-tuning--1-0-50--*" transaction startswith("Error") maxevents=20
```

Neither of those approaches returns *anything*.  The first one also surfaces a related question: how to *escape* the quotes for the fields.  Pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The way of using transaction is different. Let me brief on Splunk transaction command:

- A transaction is any group of related events that span time
- Events can come from multiple applications or hosts
- Events related to single purchase from an online store can span across an application server, database, and e-commerce engine
- One email message can create multiple events as it travels through various queues
- Each event in the network traffic logs represents a single user generating a single http request
- Visiting a single website normally generates multiple http requests

### Syntax of transaction command

```
transaction [field-list] [name=transaction-name] [transaction_definition-opt]*
```

- The events are grouped into transactions based on the values of this field list
- If a quoted list of fields is specified, events are grouped together if they have the same value for each of the fields
- Common constraints **maxspan | maxpause | maxevetns | startswith | endswith**

### How to use transaction command:

1. combine all the events by SESSIONID
   `index=index_name sourcetype=some-source-type | transaction SESSIONID`
2. With the transaction command, we can also use tables to easily view the information that we want:   `index=* | transaction SESSIONID | table SESSIONID, action, product_name`
3. transaction command: `startswith` / `endswith` : To form transactions based on terms, field values or evaluations, use `startswith` & `endswith`  options

> **Example:** the first event in the transaction includes addtocart & the last event includes purchase
>
> ```
> index=* sourcetype=access* | transaction clientip \
>       startswith=action="addtocart" endswith=action="purchase"
> ```
>
> **In your case, you need to use the last shown example.**

NOTE: Use transaction when you need to see events correlated together and also must define event grouping based on start / end values.

Comment: Hi Surya,  my impression is the answer here is a collection of cut and paste from help manuals.  I have a specific usage question: can you identify more or less why the second command in my OP did not work?